# How can I retrieve the password policy in LDAP?

Tags: java, ldap

I am trying to figure out what the password policy for a system is.  Al I could dig up is that the password policy is stored in LDAP in a field called "userPassword" with the following details.  But I can't figure out how to read the rules.  I am using JXPlorer to connect to the database.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
EQUALITY:
octetStringMatch

NAME:
userPassword

objectClass:
synthetic_JXplorer_schema_object
top


OID:
2.5.4.35

SYNTAX:
1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.40

SYNTAX Description:
Octet String

X-ORIGIN:
RFC 4519
```

Answer (score 0):

In LDAP, the password is stored in the userPassword attribute.
The password policy is a server side configuration. There is no official finalized standard for LDAP password policy, but an internet draft which has been implemented by various vendors, but not all.
Servers that implement that internet draft expose an operational attribute in each user entry : pwdPolicySubentry, and the value is the DN of the password policy enforced for that user.

> $ ldapsearch -p 1389 -D cn=directory\ manager -w secret12 -b "" '(uid=bjensen)' dn pwdPolicySubentry
>
> dn: uid=bjensen,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
>
> pwdPolicySubentry: cn=Default Password Policy,cn=Password Policies,cn=config